# Skype is reporting as out-of-date, APT disagrees

Tags: skype

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit edition) on my computer, and Skype version 4.1 currently installed. Microsoft is reporting that my current version of Skype is out of date, and an upgrade is required.

I attempted to download the `.deb` file from Microsoft's site, but it fails to install.

Running `sudo apt-get install skype` shows that my current version of Skype is up-to-date. What is going on, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of that message demanding you to upgrade Skype? Also, what does `dpkg -l | grep skype` and `apt policy skype` say?

Comment: I say you remove your current version of skype by using 'purge' then download the deb file from Microsofts website and use 'dpkg'.

Comment: sudo apt-add-repository https://repo.skype.com/deb then sudo apt-get update

Comment: Hello and welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I would highly recommend reading our [tour] to get a better idea as to how to make the best of our site.

Answer (score 2):

From the [official download page](https://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/):

> **Important notice:** All Skype for Linux clients version 4.3 and older will be retired on July 1, 2017. To keep chatting, please install the latest version of Skype for Linux.

Older versions of Skype for Linux (identified by package name `skype`) are as of now considered out of date and will be sunset soon. In order to continue using Skype, you will need to install the latest beta version (now linked to from the main page), package name `skypeforlinux`.

Uninstall the older Skype using the following command:

```
sudo apt remove skype skype-bin
```

Once the old Skype is uninstalled, install the new one:

```
wget https://go.skype.com/skypeforlinux-64.deb && \
sudo dpkg -i skypeforlinux-64.deb && sudo apt -f install && \
rm skypeforlinux-64.deb
```

From this point on, you will need to launch the "Skype For Linux" app, not the old "Skype" app.

If you'd rather use `apt` to install Skype For Linux, run these commands instead of the above install commands:

```
dpkg -s apt-transport-https > /dev/null || bash -c "sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https -y" 
curl https://repo.skype.com/data/SKYPE-GPG-KEY | sudo apt-key add - 
echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install skypeforlinux
```

Any new updates to `skypeforlinux` will be distributed through APT.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo apt purge skype` to remove it. Then `cd Downloads/` and `sudo dpkg -i [skype file here]`. Then just type skype to run it. Hope this helps...

Comment: also:  you may have the latest linux version, but not the latest windows version.  update skype in windows since windows is complaining.

Comment: @ravery There hasn't been Windows mentioned anywhere. We're only talking about Skype for Ubuntu here.

Comment: @byte Commander  he mentions Microsoft twice "Microsoft demands upgrade" and "sudo apt-get install -y skype tells me that I have an up to date version Microsoft disgrees."  Microsoft=Windows

Comment: @ravery No. Microsoft is the company that created Skype (and Windows). You can have Skype without Windows.

Comment: I agree with @ByteCommander

Comment: Microsoft did not create skype, they bought it and replaced MSN

Comment: Irrelevant information @ravery. Lets all stop arguing and help this man out.

Comment: agreed ...  first we need to make sure he has the skype repo added to apt. the ubuntu/conical repos may have an old skype